# SASS issue with nested calc

Tags: css, vue.js, npm, sass

I have some SASS variables in a vue.js project:

```
$link_height_1: calc(25vw + 10.4vh - 32px);
$rel_height_1: calc(25vw + 14.5vh - 32px);
$desc_rel_height: 32vh;
```

Then I obtain this variable with calculation of the three above:

```
$bg_rel_height_1: calc(100vh - #{$link_height_1} - #{$rel_height_1} - #{$desc_rel_height});
```

Running `npm run serve` I obtain the correct result:

```
height: calc(100vh - (calc(25vw + 10.4vh - 32px)) - (calc(25vw + 14.5vh - 32px)) - (32vh));
```

but after running `npm run build` the result is:

```
height: calc(100vh - 25vw + 10.4vh - 32px - 25vw + 14.5vh + 32px - 32vh);
```

and I can't understand why this difference. Has anyone else had such an experience?

Comment: Does it give the same result?

Comment: Not at all, since the signs in the calculation are incorrect

Comment: Perhaps different version of `node-sass` are being used for the two npm scripts. You could try; **1)** `cd` to your project directory. **2)** run `npm list node-sass` to show the parts of your dependency tree where `node-sass` is installed and check versions.

Comment: And removing the parenthesis is correct behavior? "all inner calc()s (no matter how deeply nested) will be flattened to just parentheses"  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Nested_calc_with_CSS_Variables

Comment: @anderssonola flattening nested calc to simple parentheses could be right, if only it would respect the minus sign before the expressions. It simply remove the parentheses, instead